# Can I wrap callback function into another to return a value from it?

Tags: json, kotlin, request

I have a request to a server (I am using VK SDK). So I want to move all the stuff to a different place, then call it and get response back.
Here is what I have now:

```
object GetAlbumsService {
    fun getAlbums():GetAlbumsResponse{
        lateinit var responseObject: GetAlbumsResponse
        val request = VKRequest("photos.getAlbums", VKParameters.from("need_system", "1"))
        request.executeWithListener(object: VKRequest.VKRequestListener(){
            override fun onComplete(response: VKResponse?) {
                responseObject = Gson().fromJson(response?.json.toString(), GetAlbumsResponse::class.java)
            }
        })
        return responseObject
    }
}
```

But responseObject remains `null`. Am I right that `onComplete` function have no time to fill `responseObject`? If so, what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can't return the result of an asynchronous callback from the function that initiates the background work. But you can allow the calling function to pass a callback.

```
fun getAlbums(onComplete: (GetAlbumsResponse) -> Unit) {
        val request = VKRequest("photos.getAlbums", VKParameters.from("need_system", "1"))
        request.executeWithListener(object: VKRequest.VKRequestListener(){
            override fun onComplete(response: VKResponse?) {
                responseObject = Gson().fromJson(response?.json.toString(), GetAlbumsResponse::class.java)
                onComplete(responseObject)
            }
        })
    }
```

Then from where you call this:

```
GetAlbumsService.getAlbums { response ->
    // Do something with response
}
```

The code inisde the lambda is called when the result is ready.

You can also look into using coroutines, but that's too much to explain from scratch in an answer here.